# convert to string in Maple 15

Tags: string, version, maple

```
convert(file.ext,string)
```

gives a different result depending on the Maple's current version in use. In Maple v14 gives "file.ext" but in Maple v15 gives "file . ext" (with spaces before and after the point). Can anybody explain me this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference, but more important is that the approach to form the string in this manner is misguided.

There are no special (delayed) evaluation rules for the command `convert`, and what that routine sees as the first argument here is the result of the (noncommutating) multiplication of the name `file` with the name `ext`. And so that's not really a great way to concatenate to a string, because it's purpose is not to first carefully concatenate.

There are alternatives. You could concatenate to a single name, and then convert that to a string, or you could concatenate directly to a string (for which the command convert/string is not best).

```
 # I'm supposing that one does want the name`file` assigned
 file:=myproject:

 # Now suppose that one wants the result "myproject.for"
 ext:=`for`:

 convert(file.ext,string); # whoops
                  "myproject . `for`"

 cat(file,".",ext); # produces the name `myproject.for`
                     myproject.for

 convert(%,string);
                    "myproject.for"

 sprintf("%a.%s",file,ext);
                    "myproject.for"
```